# how to convert InkML file to png or jpg in python?

Tags: python, image, ocr, conv-neural-network, inkml

I am trying to make a CNN model for OCR using handwritten notes, the dataset contains files in InkML format, I searched on the web but could not find any proper documentation on this. Please let me know how to convert the InkML files to png so that I can train my model

Comment: Did you try this? https://www.kaggle.com/kalikichandu/preprossing-inkml-to-png-files

Comment: yes I had already tried that approach, It works only on the dataset that is present in that kernel. When I tried to do that approach using a new inkml file(which is not present in that kernel) then I don't get any output file(I don't even get any kind off error, the code executes perfectly but no result is generated)